# How can I solve this optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

How do I solve this optimisation problem?

$$W = \left(\frac{n(X-Y-Z)p}{Zq}\right)^{1/a},\, a>0$$

$\operatorname{Max}\{ W\}$, subject to $0\leq n \leq 1$,  $0\leq Y \leq X$ and $Z \leq Z_{max}$

What is the optimum value of $n$ and $Y$ in the equation?

If i add another constant, it is possible to solve
another constants: $Z \leq Z_{max}$

Comment: What about $Z$? Do they take values over the reals? Integers?

Comment: Z is real value, it is not integers. like a fraction value 0.2-0.5

Comment: And there are no constraints on $Z$?

Comment: range of Z between 0.2 and 0.5